# ssh tunnel not opening via cron job

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh, cron

I want to create ssh tunnel via cron job. My cron job is running (log is also generated) but ssh tunnel is not opening.
Here is cron job code:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/ssh -p 22796 -L 8080:mysql:3306 user@hostname && echo 'It works!'>> /var/log/cron_ssh.log 2>&1
```

I am using Amazon Linux 2 AMI.

Comment: why do you want to run an extra ssh every minute of every hour of every day? how is your root user configured to let ssh access security credentials (eg. password, private key)? What makes you think the tunnel is not opening?

Comment: I am trying to connect to mysql, hosted on MageMojo, using SSH. When I run this command in the terminal, SSH tunnel is created. But, when I close the terminal, the SSH tunnel also closed. I have generated an SSH key via SSH-keygen on EC2 instance and placed it on MageMojo. Now, I want a process which can create SSH tunnel automatically. To do so, I have written the cronjob.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you try to create a new tunnel every minute. Why do you think the tunnel is not opening when you run from cron?

Comment: You could put the `ssh` process in the background by using `&`, but I agree with @jhnc -- this isn't something you would want to do every minute. Also, instead of sending "It works" to a log file, you could send the output of the ssh command to the log.

Comment: I checked on cron log. This error message show "pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." that's why ssh tunnel is not establish through cron job. I have fixed this issue by using -tt in ssh command. @john thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I believe you will find that the tunnel *was* established, even without `-tt`. For example, check the `last` output on hostname. However, ssh would immediately terminate because, without `-tt`, the remote shell got /dev/null for stdin and exited.